# How to delete huge amount of records from MySQL using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a MySQL table that contains millions of records and there is a purpose to delete all this records using Spring Data JPA. But there is a problem with out of memory that occurs during `deleteAll()` method execution. I also tried `deleteAllInBatch()`, but it stacks during the execution after around 30 minutes of deletion.
Is there any option that could resolve such issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Use a native `delete from <table>` query. that shouldn't make the java application run into a memory issue. And deleting millions of record shouldn't take that long. maybe if you get into the billions? just tested with about 5.5m records and a native query took 1 min and 30 seconds

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score -2):

Just add repository in your project like this add method:
void deleteByIdIn(List ids);